# Is it possible to recover a permemnantly deleted file on EXT partition?

Tags: partitioning, software-recommendation, data-recovery, alternative

I've migrated from Windows to Ubuntu, So searching all those back up tools and software alternatives with Windows to Linux.

For Windows, there exists *RECOVA*, *GetDataBack* Disk **recovery softwares**; but those are for only **NTFS** & **FAT** don't have **EXT** partition support.

For Ubuntu, is there any Package for recovery?

Comment: Please note that once a file was (even partly) overwriteen it can not be recovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few options may be.

---

http://www.acronis.com/en-us/business/backup/linux-server/

http://www.r-tt.com/free_linux_recovery/Download.shtml

http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

http://www.easeus.com/data-recovery/data-recovery-software/linux-ext2-ext3-data-recovery-freeware.htm

---

To prevent future issues try a program called TimeShift to create backups

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:teejee2008/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install timeshift
```